# Simple random numbers game program

Tags: c, if-statement, while-loop, srand

Here is my code, It is a simple number game where the user tries to guess the random number however, I can not figure out why it you never win..There are two things i am having trouble solving 1) The user never guesses the correct number 2) I want to have a cap of 3 tries of guessing although I cant seem catch what i'm overlooking

```
// C_program_random_number_game

#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>




int main(){

srand(time(NULL));
int num1,x;
char game, cont, replay;
printf("Would you like to play a game? : ");
scanf("%c",&game);
if (game == 'y' || game == 'Y'){

    printf("\nThe rules are simple. You have have 5 tries to guess the computers number. \n \n If you succeed you win the game, if you dont you lose the game. Good luck!");
    do{
    int r = rand()%25 +1;
    printf("\n\nEnter a number between 1 and 5 : ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    do{
    for(x=1; x<=3; x++){

    if(num1 < r){
        printf("\nClose! try a little higher... : ");
    }
    else if (num1 > r){
        printf("\nClose! try a little lower...: ");
    }
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    }
    }while(num1!=r || x <= 3);
    printf("\nWinner! >> you entered %d and the computer generated %d! \n",num1, r);
    printf("\nWould you like to play again? (y or n) : ");
    scanf("\n%c",&replay);
    }while(replay == 'y'|| replay == 'Y');
}
    printf("Thanks for playing! ");

    if (game == 'n' || game == 'N'){
    printf("Okay, maybe next time! ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You put `(num1 == r)` in `(num1 != r)`....

Comment: Im confused... Do I switch them?

Comment: well it just makes no sense because the while loop makes sure that num1 != r and then inside you check to see if it is equal.. which will thus never be true

Comment: You should probably use `while (true)` and later in the branch `else if(num1 == r){ }`, add a `break` statement to exit the loop. Also, it would be helpful for diagnosis if you give a short input/output sequence.

Comment: Thanks man! huge help! my eyes were hurting from looking at this small code haha...Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

One definite problem is that the format specifier is incorrect:

```
scanf("&d",&num1);
```

should be:

```
scanf("%d",&num1);
```

Moreover, the last 2 conditions in your `while` loop would never be evaluated since it'd not enter the loop if the guess is equal to the random number.  Use a `do-while` loop instead to loop *infinitely*, and `break` out of it as per the user input.  Remember to take user input for the guess *within the loop*.

Comment: Thank you for the help! I changed it to the do while though it still does not seem to be reaching it past judging the HIGH or LOW conditions...any idea why?

Comment: @Djeter277 Use an infinite loop, i.e. `do {} while(1);`.  `break` out of it as per your needs.

Comment: @Djeter277 I know why, as I explain in my answer

Answer (score 1):

There are various flaws, here is the code you are looking for:

```
while(num1 != r){
    if(num1 < r){
        printf("higher... : ");
    }
    else{
        printf("lower...: ");
    }
    scanf("%d",&num1);
}
printf("Winner! >> you entered %d and the computer generated %d! \n",num1, r);
printf("Would you like to play again? (y or n) : ");
scanf("%c",&replay);
```

As I pointed out in the comment above, previously, inside the while loop, there would never be a time when num1==r and thus the if statement inside will never be true. Now, the loop jsut simply stops after it reaches the number.

Comment: Hey man thanks a lot! would have looked over that all night haha..THANKS YOU!

Comment: you click the check next to an answer if it is the answer you choose as correct